# Ruby selenium webdriver drag and drop

Tags: ruby, drag-and-drop, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to perform drag and drop operation using selenium webdriver and ruby, and I tried the following options:

Option 1: based on http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/0.0.28/Selenium/WebDriver/Element#drag_and_drop_on-instance_method

```
el1 = @driver.find_element(:css, "div.captcha div.sliderCaptcha div.arrow")
el2 = @driver.find_element(:css, "div.captcha div.sliderCaptcha div.dottedBorder")

el1.drag_and_drop_on el2
```

Option 2:

```
el1 = @driver.find_element(:css, "div.captcha div.sliderCaptcha div.arrow")
el2 = @driver.find_element(:css, "div.captcha div.sliderCaptcha div.dottedBorder")
@driver.action.drag_and_drop(el1, el2).perform
```

Option 3:

```
el1 = @driver.find_element(:css, "div.captcha div.sliderCaptcha div.arrow")
el2 = @driver.find_element(:css, "div.captcha div.sliderCaptcha div.dottedBorder")
@browser.action.drag_and_drop(element, target).perform
```

when I do `@driver.find_element(:css, "div.captcha div.sliderCaptcha div.arrow").click` or `@driver.find_element(:css, "div.captcha div.sliderCaptcha div.dottedBorder").click` the code is able to click object, i.e. it is able to find element but due to some reason not able to drag and drop. None of above drag and drop option worked.

Comment: a little strange to see using of driver directly without Capybara interface. In Capubara used first option http://rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/0.4.0/Capybara/Driver/Selenium/Node#drag_to-instance_method `def drag_to(element)
  native.drag_and_drop_on(element.native)
end` Also you can check visibility of both elements.

Answer (score 2):

I have had quite a lot of success with drag and drop, but found that I had to split my drag and drop into several actions to allow it to work in my app.

For example, I had to sleep 500 ms after the initial click as the javascript required the user to hold  down for that period before allowing drag and drop to occur. Also, I had to refind the drop target after the initial drag as it only appeared after the drag started.

I am not saying this is occuring in your application, but it may give you some hints.

For example, my code looked something like this;

```
el1 = @driver.find_element(:css, "div.captcha div.sliderCaptcha div.arrow")

el_in_between = @driver.find_element(:css, "div.something")

@browser.action.click_and_hold(el1).perform

sleep 0.5

@browser.action.move_to(el_in_between).perform

el2 = @driver.find_element(:css, "div.captcha div.sliderCaptcha div.dottedBorder")

@browser.action.move_to(el2).release.perform
```

Hopefully this highlights that in some websites, drag and drop is not quite as simple as using a built in drag_and_drop method and that an action builder can be split

Comment: I tried the above solution. But it does not work for me. I am trying to automate signup process of https://secure.photobucket.com/register. It have a arrow to slide. And I am trying to do it using selenium-webdriver script.

Comment: Ha! The heading above the arrow says "Slide the arrow to prove you are human". It is not supposed to be automatable! Why are you automating this page?

Comment: I need it to automate because my project need it.